# What is the difference between this 3 query

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any difference between this 3 query?

query 1

```
$query = "INSERT INTO reserve( c_id, c_username, r_id, r_name, checkin, checkout)";
$query .= " VALUES ( $c_id, $c_username, $r_id, $r_name, $checkin, $checkout )";
```

query 2

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reserve( c_id, c_username, r_id, r_name, checkin, checkout)
VALUES ( '$c_id' , '$c_username', '$r_id', '$r_name', '$checkin', '$checkout' )";
```

query 3

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO reserve (c_id, c_username, r_id, r_name, checkin, checkout) VALUES ('$c_id' , '$c_username', '$r_id', '$r_name', '$checkin', '$checkout');")
```

And which one should I use to select a data from my database and which one should I use to insert data into database

Comment: None of them.  Learn to use parameters properly for passing parameters into a query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff do you know where I can learn about query...w3school is not that helping.......Considering i have zero knowledge regarding mysqli query.  Thank you for your reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On a quickly glance they all appear to do the same thing. You don't need to learn parameter passing at your stage. Be aware of injection attacks and clean those variables before you do calls.

I tend to do this for readability:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reserve(c_id
                           ,c_username
                           ,r_id
                           ,r_name
                           ,checkin
                           ,checkout)
                   VALUES ('$c_id'
                          ,'$c_username'
                          ,'$r_id'
                          ,'$r_name'
                          ,'$checkin'
                          ,'$checkout')";
```